# Dealing with three Windows partitions in dual boot installation

Tags: 10.04, dual-boot, windows-7

1. For dual-boot installation of Ubuntu
   after Windows. Quoted from
   [ubuntuguide](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Multiple_OS_Installation#Partition_design)

   > If a Windows boot partition exists as
   >   a second NTFS partition, it should be
   >   left alone. If there is a Windows
   >   recovery partition also installed, it
   >   can also be left alone as long as
   >   there are only two NTFS partitions
   >   total on the hard drive (i.e. there is
   >   no NTFS boot partition as well). If
   >   there are a total of 3 NTFS partitions
   >   on the hard drive, then the third
   >   Windows NTFS partition (the recovery
   >   partition) should be removed after
   >   creating Recovery CDs from it (see
   >   here).

   In the last case where Windows has three
   partitions, I was wondering why it
   says the recovery partition shall be
   removed? Is it possible to keep the three and create
   another extended partition with
   several logical partitions for
   installing Ubuntu and dual-booting
   the two OSes?
2. I plan to dual-boot install Ubuntu
   10.04 with existing Windows 7. Following is the layout of the
   current partitions of my hard drive
   viewed from Windows 7:
   [image: alttext]

   So must I remove the Lenovo_Recovery
   (Q:) partition for the same reason
   you give for the first question?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally just resize `Windows7_OS`, leaving a gap between it and `Lenovo_Recovery`. Then just install Ubuntu in the space using the "alongside existing operating systems" option in the graphical installer.

I can't see any reason to run around deleting the recovery partition.

### *But remember:* Back-up anything you can't reinstall.